# Opencv linking CMAKE not working Ubuntu 16.04 Docker

Tags: c++, docker, opencv, ubuntu, cmake

I am trying to compile a project inside a Docker file but it keeps throwing errors.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM jjanzic/docker-python3-opencv:contrib-opencv-3.4.2

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y g++ cmake libboost-dev libgoogle-perftools-dev

COPY . /opt/nsg

WORKDIR /opt/nsg

RUN mkdir -p build && cd build && \
    cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .. && \
    make -j $(nproc)
```

**CMakeLists.txt** in root directory:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(efanna2e)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
#OpenMP
find_package(OpenMP)
if (OPENMP_FOUND)
    set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
    set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "no OpenMP supprot")
endif()
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fno-builtin-malloc -fno-builtin-calloc -fno-builtin-realloc -fno-builtin-free")
add_definitions (-std=c++14 -O3 -lboost -march=native -Wall -DINFO)

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(tests)
```

**CMakeLists.txt** in `/tests` directory:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(test_nsg_index test_nsg_index.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_nsg_index ${PROJECT_NAME} -ltcmalloc)

add_executable(test_nsg_search test_nsg_search.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_nsg_search ${PROJECT_NAME})

add_executable(test_nsg_optimized_search test_nsg_optimized_search.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_nsg_optimized_search ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(test_nsg_optimized_search ${PROJECT_NAME} -ltcmalloc)
```

Code I want to run:

```
auto body = req.body.substr(file.offset, file.length);
const cv::Mat image = cv::imdecode(body, 0);
```

After running `docker build .` this is part of the output:

```
-- Found OpenCV: /usr/local (found version "3.4.2") 

/opt/nsg/tests/test_nsg_optimized_search.cpp:149:4:   required from here
/opt/nsg/tests/test_nsg_optimized_search.cpp:145:39: error: no matching function for call to ‘imdecode(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&, int)’
     const cv::Mat image = cv::imdecode(body, 0);
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs.hpp:48:0,
                 from /opt/nsg/tests/test_nsg_optimized_search.cpp:12:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp:222:18: note: candidate: cv::Mat cv::imdecode(cv::InputArray, int)
 CV_EXPORTS_W Mat imdecode( InputArray buf, int flags );
                  ^~~~~~~~
```

So it keeps saying that there is no function `imdecode`. I also tried `imread` and multiple other functions. It just keeps saying it is not there, and on the next line it says that it found the function I want and points to it.

I have tried multiple things in my code:

1. I loaded `#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>`
2. Then I loaded `#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"` (did that for all included hpp files from opencv
3. used: `using namespace cv;`
4. used the function without the namespace
5. did: `cv::imdecode()`
6. did: `imdecode()`

These **all** resulted in the same error.

Yesterday I was on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine with the same exact problem, except that I installed opencv on the machine and not via Docker. Today, I reinstalled Ubuntu to version 16.04 and started using Docker. But again same problem. I think I am doing something wrong here but don't know what.

Comment: What is the underlying type of `cv::InputArray`? Does it match what you give for the function argument (`std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&`)?

Comment: from the documentation `The function imdecode reads an image from the specified buffer in the memory. If the buffer is too short or contains invalid data, the function returns an empty matrix ( Mat::data==NULL ).` and `buf Input array or vector of bytes.` can be found here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga26a67788faa58ade337f8d28ba0eb19e  Even if the input that I provide is incorrect this should work.

Comment: "*Even if the input that I provide is incorrect this should work.*" - I don't think that is necessarily correct, your input `body` is not of the correct **type**. The [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d32/classcv_1_1__InputArray.html) say that `InputArray` is "a class that can be constructed from Mat, Mat_<T>, Matx<T, m, n>, std::vector<T>, std::vector<std::vector<T> >, std::vector<Mat>, std::vector<Mat_<T> >, UMat, std::vector<UMat> or double."

Comment: I am back in 2 hours to check if you are correct, i will use imread and use a jpg image to be sure my input is correct. Why do you thing I get an error saying the function is not defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that the function call:

```
const cv::Mat image = cv::imdecode(body, 0);
```

doesn't match what is defined in the header file. The compiler only knows how to use calls matching the function signatures (i.e. function name, function argument types, return type, etc) that are defined, in your case in `imgcodecs.hpp`:

```
cv::Mat cv::imdecode(cv::InputArray, int)
```

The compiler calls this a *candidate* match, because while the function name you used, `imdecode`, is correct, the function argument **types** do not match. Your function call has this signature (per the error message), showing the first argument is different than what the compiler expects:

```
cv::Mat imdecode(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&, int)
```

So you have to change the variable `body` to be a `cv::InputArray` type, or a type from which `InputArray` can be constructed. The list of possibilities is [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d32/classcv_1_1__InputArray.html#details). Considering a `cv::InputArray` can be constructed from a `std::vector<T>` type, you may try converting `body` into a vector of `char` with something like this:

```
auto body = req.body.substr(file.offset, file.length);
std::vector<char> bodyVector(body.begin(), body.end());
const cv::Mat image = cv::imdecode(bodyVector, 0);
```

Or you can explicitly create a `cv::InputArray` variable from `body` and pass that to the `imdecode` function instead.

Comment: This indeed is correct. I was getting confused because I thought it was pointing me in a different direction.